# Continuous Deployment using Codeship

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, open-source, web-deployment

I'm using [code ship](https://www.codeship.io/) for deploy a **node.js project in heroku**.I'm dong it using [this](http://blog.codeship.io/2013/10/08/how-to-deploy-a-node-js-app-from-github-to-heroku.html) tutorial.I have setup a git repository with the node js project in **bitbucket**.

In one step it ask to hook codeship with bitbucket.I have successfully done it.but this message **keeps on coming** , with out going to the next step.Please help me out with this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you push a new commit to your Bitbucket repository, this will trigger your first build and the message will disappear.